# JavaScript and object access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, object

I have this basic JavaScript code as part of a mini file-manager project I'm making for fun, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Inside the `get()` function, I'm trying to access the `Content.files` array but it seems that due to variable scope or whatever inside the function, it's not setting the array correctly and nothing appears on the page. Firefox's Error Console gives me nothing. How do I fix this?

By the way, lately I've been focusing on C# and PHP so forgive me if it's just a stupid syntax error. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Page = {

currentdir: '/',
}

Content = {

files:[], folders:[],

get: function() {

    $.post('?p=myfiles&ajax', {
        dir: '/',
    }, function (data) {
        Content.files = data.files;
        Content.folders = data.folders;
    }, "json"); 
},

build: function () {

    for (var n = 0; n < Content.files.length; n++) {

        var id = Content.files[n].id;
        var name = Content.files[n].name;
        var size = Content.files[n].size;

        output = '<td>File</td><td>'+id+'</td><td><a href="?p=file-download&id='+id+'">'+name+'</a></td><td>'+((size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2))+' MB</td>';

        $('#filetable').append('<tr>'+output+'</tr>');

    }
},

}

</script>
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: The Content.files variable is never set, so accessing it later in the build() function pulls up nothing.

Comment: You'll have to call `Content.build();` inside the callback for `$.post`, since `$.post` is asynchronous. `build` executes immediately after `get` in your example comment, but the AJAX request sent by `get` isn't returning the results until after `build` has been called because it's asynchronous

Comment: Thanks Ian!  That worked, I just added a method overload for get() to ask it whether or not to run build() after the ajax request.

Comment: @user1653653 No problem! I added an answer to explain fully, and with some extra details to come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comment that you deleted (I'm guessing because I mis-deleted my own comment), you are calling the `build` method immediately after calling `get`. Unfortunately, `get` makes an AJAX request that is asynchronous. That means, Javascript won't wait for the AJAX response before running further code, therefore running `build` immediately after sending the request. The response will come back at some point in the future (not too long from now), but almost definitely not before `build` is called. That means that the items won't be populated. Here's an example of how to provide a callback:

```
var Page = {   // <-- Add `var`
    currentdir: '/',
};

var Content = {   // <-- Add `var`
    files:[],
    folders:[],
    get: function (callback) {
        $.post('?p=myfiles&ajax', {
            dir: '/',
        }, function (data) {
            Content.files = data.files;
            Content.folders = data.folders;
            //if (typeof callback !== "undefined") { // <-- Might be better than below, in the special cases where some functions are "objects" in IE
            if (typeof callback === "function") {
                Function.prototype.apply.call(this, callback, arguments);
            }
        }, "json");
    },
    build: function () {
        for (var n = 0; n < Content.files.length; n++) {
            var id = Content.files[n].id;
            var name = Content.files[n].name;
            var size = Content.files[n].size;
            output = '<td>File</td><td>'+id+'</td><td><a href="?p=file-download&id='+id+'">'+name+'</a></td><td>'+((size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2))+' MB</td>';
            $('#filetable').append('<tr>'+output+'</tr>');
        }
    }    // <-------------- Remove the comma
};

Content.get(Content.build);
```

This way, you could pass any function reference to `Content.get` and it will be called immediately after the `Content.files` and `Content.folders` are populated from the AJAX request.

A few other things - remove the comma after the `build` method in the `Content` object. Also, you should probably use `var` to declare the `Page` and `Content` objects.

Answer (score -1):

`Content` would not be defined yet since you're actually in the *process* of defining it, but in the object scope you can refer to it with `this`.  The post callback has its own scope, but you can just reassign `this` in the higher scope.

```
get: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.post('?p=myfiles&ajax', {
        dir: '/',
    }, function (data) {
        self.files = data.files;
        self.folders = data.folders;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xYByU/

It's also important to note that you have no idea when the `$.post` method will finish running, so any dependency on `Content` being filled has to rely on that request completing.

Answer (score -2):

You're going to want to use `this.files` instead of `Content.files` inside of your object. `Content` is the reference you're making to the object that's being created. *Maybe* you can close over its value like you're doing, I honestly don't know, but it smells bad and that's really what the implicit `this` variable is for. *Outside* of your object, once it's been assigned to the variable `Content`, it's correct to say `Content.files` to refer to that member variable.

As a side note, it's better practice to enclose your script in an immediately-called anonymous function, so as not to risk clashing with other members of the `window` object, which can happen if you don't use `var` to declare your variables or you create variables outside of the scope of a function (you're doing both).  I would read over [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function) to get a better understanding of this.